# How to exchange google oauth access token for ID token?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth, google-oauth

I'm migrating to using [this react component](https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth/) to implement Google Oauth since [this one has been deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login).

The old component gives me a JWT which I can then decode (on my backend) using my Google secret to get information like the users profile photo, email address, and first and last name.

The new component gives me either a `access_token` or a `code` depending on the value provided for `flow`. It's not clear to me how I can exchange either of these tokens for the JWT which I previously used to get user information.

I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types#access) endpoint which exchanges an `access_token` for an email and a bit more info.

How can I swap either an `access_token` or `code` for an ID token which contains all of the relevant user info needed for my webapp?